# Problem installing Spring Boot or running any .jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, installation, path, spring-tools-4

I'm trying to install Spring Boot STS but unfortunately I always get the same error (sorry for the blacked up part in path in pictures, my name is shown)

[Error I get when I try to run Spring Boot after downloading it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKj9K.jpg)

Things I tried:

1. Installed Java from Java Oracle (I tried versions 18,17 and 8 all giving me the same error in Spring Boot STS)
2. When I run Java -version in command prompt it seems it is installed correctly
3. Configured my environment variables in System Variables
   [in Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac3Ag.jpg) and also I put in User variables [PATH and CROSSPATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utGF4.jpg)
4. Tried to install Eclipse but get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnxE4.jpg)
5. Tried Jarfix, doesn't work
6. Tried run.bat with java -jar FileName.jar, doesn't work
7. Tried reinstalling everything and restarting my laptop,nothing works

Do you have any suggestions what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on windows and your path looks like the jar file is in a user specific Directory it might be a authentication issue.

Try:

```
Move jar fiele to example c:/test/test.jar
```

and run in command inside c:/test:

```
java -jar test.jar
```